# Rearranging a sublist within a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I am having a hard time rearanging a list of tuples of names, first and last. I want to sort the list by last name and if there are identical last names then the sublist of those names should be arranged by first name. The first part was pretty easy with sorted and key=get_key1 but I am having diffuculties to complete the second part of the problem.

A list like this:

```
[('Tom','Haim'),('Eli','Levi'),('Eli','Cohen'),('Moshe','Levi'),('Haim','Cohen'),('Dina','Ram'),('Tova','Ben'),('Ben','Levi'),('Gil','Cohen'),('Eli','Ram')]
```

should come out like:

```
[('Tova', 'Ben'), ('Eli', 'Cohen'), ('Gil', 'Cohen'), ('Haim', 'Cohen'), ('Tom', 'Haim'), ('Ben', 'Levi'), ('Eli', 'Levi'), ('Moshe', 'Levi'), ('Dina', 'Ram'), ('Eli', 'Ram')]
```

Best I got is:

```
[('Tova', 'Ben'), ('Eli', 'Cohen'), ('Haim', 'Cohen'), ('Gil', 'Cohen'), ('Tom', 'Haim'), ('Eli', 'Levi'), ('Moshe', 'Levi'), ('Ben', 'Levi'), ('Dina', 'Ram'), ('Eli', 'Ram')]
```

Thank you

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: which programming language your using ?

Comment: Im using python

Answer (score 2):

If you return a tuple as a key it will first sort by the first element and then by the second. Since you want to sort by first last name then first name your key should return `(last name, first name)`.

```
l = [('Tom','Haim'),('Eli','Levi'),('Eli','Cohen'),('Moshe','Levi'),('Haim','Cohen'),('Dina','Ram'),('Tova','Ben'),('Ben','Levi'),('Gil','Cohen'),('Eli','Ram')]

def get_key1(x):
    return (x[1], x[0])

print(sorted(l, key=get_key1))
```

Comment: Excellent! thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list of the fly using the `sort()` method of `list`:

```
inlist = [('Tom','Haim'),('Eli','Levi'),('Eli','Cohen'),('Moshe','Levi'),('Haim','Cohen'),('Dina','Ram'),('Tova','Ben'),('Ben','Levi'),('Gil','Cohen'),('Eli','Ram')]
inlist.sort(key = lambda i: (i[1],i[0]))
print(inlist)
```

Output:

```
[('Tova', 'Ben'), ('Eli', 'Cohen'), ('Gil', 'Cohen'), ('Haim', 'Cohen'), ('Tom', 'Haim'), ('Ben', 'Levi'), ('Eli', 'Levi'), ('Moshe', 'Levi'), ('Dina', 'Ram'), ('Eli', 'Ram')]
```

An alternative to `lambda`, suggested by @cezar would be `itemgetter` from the `operator` module:

```
from operator import itemgetter

inlist = [('Tom','Haim'),('Eli','Levi'),('Eli','Cohen'),('Moshe','Levi'),('Haim','Cohen'),('Dina','Ram'),('Tova','Ben'),('Ben','Levi'),('Gil','Cohen'),('Eli','Ram')]

inlist.sort(key = itemgetter(1,0))
print(inlist)
```

Output:

```
[('Tova', 'Ben'), ('Eli', 'Cohen'), ('Gil', 'Cohen'), ('Haim', 'Cohen'), ('Tom', 'Haim'), ('Ben', 'Levi'), ('Eli', 'Levi'), ('Moshe', 'Levi'), ('Dina', 'Ram'), ('Eli', 'Ram')]
```

Comment: Good answer! I'd however prefer slightly different version using `itemgetter` (`from operator import itemgetter`). The command would look like this: `inlist.sort(key=itemgetter(1, 0))`. I think that's more comprehensible than using `lambda`.